# I cannot get teleop_base

Tags: ros, teleop-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure why but I cannot checkout teleop_base. Please let me know if I miss anything. Is there another way to get it?

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~/Documents/WorkSpaceROS$ svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/teleop_base teleop_base
svn: E000110: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/teleop_base'
svn: E000110: Error running context: Connection timed out
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229911/i-cannot-get-teleop_base/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That server has long since been taken off-line.

There appears to be a copy at [Hudhaifa/teleop_base](https://github.com/Hudhaifa/teleop_base), but looking at [teleop_base deprecated, need generic teleop package](http://answers.ros.org/question/9207/teleop_base-deprecated-need-generic-teleop-package/) here on ROS Answers, the packages in [github.com/ros-teleop](https://github.com/ros-teleop) are intended to replace `teleop_base`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-03-23**:
Thanks gvdhoorn. Some one need to update this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-23**:\

> Some one need to update this tutorial

Could you do it? :)

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-03-23**:
I will tried this tonight after work.
Can you tell me specific command I should use to get the package from git? Is it

```
git clone -b indigo-devel https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard
```

Then call catkin_make first before I can run it?
Thank you

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-23**:
There is no `indigo-devel` branch in `teleop_twist_keyboard`, and I would recommend installing the released version (`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-teleop-twist-keyboard`), but if you must use sources, then be sure to run a `rosdep check --from-paths .. --ignore-src ..` etc.